# Vue.js - target a nested property in list to use it as variable

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am using Vue.js and I have a list of items from which I need to target a property to use as a variable, unfortunately I seem to be unable to work out how I'm supposed to target the variable.

The code below hopefully gives an idea of what I'm trying to do (and where I'm going wrong).

```
var items = [
    {
        doh: `value 1a`,
        ray: `value 2a`,
        me: `value 3a`,
        fah: `value 4a`,
        soh: `value 5a`
    },
    {
        doh: `value 1b`,
        ray: `value 2b`,
        me: `value 3b`,
        fah: `value 4b`,
        soh: `value 5b`
    }
];

new Vue({
    el:`#feefoReviews`,
    data: {
       name: items
    },
    computed: {
        test: function() {
            var $result = this.items.doh;
            return $result
        }
    }
)};
```

In this case I am expecting that the "value 1a" and "value 1b" would be rendered. It isn't. If I replace the function with the following:

```
test: function() {
    return 'example'
}
```

I get example rendered to my page, so clearly I am targeting the property incorrectly. I am sure I am missing something really obvious.

Comment: The `items` is an array of objects and then assigned to `name` data property. For `value 1` try via the index: `this.name[0]['doh']`

Comment: this.name[0]['doh'] brings back the same value for each item in the list, I guess this is the [0] doing this.  What I need is each list item to have its own correct value. I've updated the example so its a little clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `map` function to return only that property:

```
 test: function() {
           return this.name.map(item=>{
              return item.doh;
           })
        }
```

that return an array like :

```
[`value 1a`, `value 1b`]
```

```js
var items = [{
    doh: `value 1a`,
    ray: `value 2a`,
    me: `value 3a`,
    fah: `value 4a`,
    soh: `value 5a`
  },
  {
    doh: `value 1b`,
    ray: `value 2b`,
    me: `value 3b`,
    fah: `value 4b`,
    soh: `value 5b`
  }
];

let app=new Vue({
    el: `#feefoReviews`,
    data: {
      name: items
    },
    computed: {
      test: function() {
        return this.name.map(item => {
          return item.doh;
        })
      }
    }
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="feefoReviews">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="item in test" :key="item">{{item}}</li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to target an object key, but the object is within an array so you're not getting a match for the key. You need to add the index of the array for the object you're trying to use.

```
test: function() {
    return this.name[0]['doh'];
}
```

Comment: @ambianBeing You're correct, I did not notice that the items array was defined outside. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, didn't see your edit. This does help a little but as I mentioned to @ambianBeing above, I'm aiming to loop through the array and bring back the value associated with each item